# Combine columns values using comma using the other column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I have table like this:

```
ID      Name
--------------
1       Ritesh
1       Raj
1       Suraj
2       John
2       Sanjay
2       Max
3       Dinesh
3       Dheeraj
```

I want to join the column values of column Name using column ID having same values of Id

The output should be in a new table with a single column:

```
NewColumn
------------------
Ritesh,Raj,Suraj
John,Sanjay,Max
Dinesh,Dheeraj
```

The first three names have same id as 1 and same as for id 2 and 3

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Comment: Not getting a clear picture still.

Comment: Maybe this one will help? http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/comma+separated+list/71700/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT D1.ID, STUFF((SELECT ','+D2.NAME FROM DATA D2 FOR XML PATH('') WHERE D1.ID = D2.ID),1,1,'') AS NAME FROM DATA D1)
SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM CTE
```