# Calculate product of column values on the basis of other column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table

```
Tid   Did    value
------------------
1     123    100
1     234    200
2     123    323
2     234    233
```

All tids have dids as 123 and 234. So for every tid having dids 123 and 234 I want the product of corresponding values

The output table will be

```
Tid   Product
------------------
1     20000 (product of 100 and 200)
2     75259 (product of 323 and 233)
```

Any help?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
select tid,
         min(case when did = 123 then value end)
       * min(case when did = 234 then value end) product
  from my_table
 group by tid
```

To get the data for multiple rows combined (based on `tid`) you use `GROUP BY`.

Because you're grouping by `tid`, you have to use an aggregate function to do anything with other values from the individual rows.  If implied assumptions hold (exactly 1 row matching each `did` for each `tid`) then it doesn't matter much what aggregate function you use; `min` is as good as anything.

Within the aggregation, you use `CASE` logic to select `value` for the required `did` (and `NULL` for all other rows in the `tid` group).

Then just do the math.

Comment: Having same relatable issue posted the question but not quite get the answer.Link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086538/combine-columns-values-using-comma-using-the-other-column-in-sql-server/45088980#45088980.Any help with this

Answer (score 0):

You can use some arithmetic to get the product per tid.

```
select tid,exp(sum(log(value))) as prod
from t
group by tid
```

To do this only for tid's having did values 123 and 234, use

```
select tid,exp(sum(log(value))) as prod
from t
group by tid
having count(distinct case when did in (123,234) then did end) = 2
```

Comment: Having same relatable issue posted the question but not quite get the answer.Link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086538/combine-columns-values-using-comma-using-the-other-column-in-sql-server/45088980#45088980 any help with this

Comment: @Ritesh maybe if these answers help with/solve your problem you can mark the correct one as accepted, then people will be more inclined to help you with other questions. or if they don't help, comment why and people can try to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Rexster](http://rextester.com/STFOH47911) solution, based on good work of @gbn [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653623/495157)

```
SELECT
    Tid,
    CASE
       WHEN MinVal = 0 THEN 0
       WHEN Neg % 2 = 1 THEN -1 * EXP(ABSMult)
       ELSE EXP(ABSMult)
    END
FROM
    (
    SELECT
       Tid,
       SUM(LOG(ABS(NULLIF(value, 0)))) AS ABSMult,
       SUM(SIGN(CASE WHEN value < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS Neg,
       MIN(ABS(value)) AS MinVal
    FROM
       t
    GROUP BY
       Tid
    ) t2
```